# Can localStorage be modified by a client?

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm attempting to use localStorage as a cookie replacement (detest cookies) so users can stay signed in on a site I operate.

What I planned so far was to save the user's username in localStorage, and have the site check whether anything was in localStorage, and if anything *is* in localStorage, it'd push the localStorage data to a PHP file via POST and push the user to start a new PHP session and return them back to where they were.

Though I have the concern, I know localStorage can be viewed, in which case possibly encrypting the data server-side would make some sense.

But can LocalStorage data be modified? If not, this would be fine to do, even without encryption, but obviously if a user could modify the localStorage data, they would have access to others' accounts, which as you can imagine, isn't a good thing.

I had the doubt because JavaScript can be executed by a client in a browser, ie:

```
javascript:alert("hello");
```

Couldn't it be possible to find out the localStorage's var name and reset it's value like this?

```
javascript:localStorage.setItem('sessionusername','superadmin');
```

Basically, I ask: Can HTML5 Local Storage data be modified on client side?

Comment: This seems like it would be relatively trivial for you to test.

Comment: As Anthony stated, how hard would it be for you to set a variable then test your theory?  You have all the code written to test it in your OP.

Comment: You should assume that any data held on the client could be altered with the right amount of skills and knowledge. If security is an issue, you should not base your application security around presistent storage or persistent cookies for that matter.

Comment: I ask because I'm using a semi-crippled device for the next few days (iPhone) and it refuses to work in the URL-bar, apologies :S

Comment: In firefox, I can go in the inspector, click on storage and modify the local storage values manually and see them reflected in my app.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Local storage is bound to the domain, so in regular case the user cannot change it on any other domain or on localhost.

It is also bound per user/browser, i.e. no third party has access to ones local storage.

Nevertheless local storage is in the end a file on the user's file system and may be hacked.

Comment: Is i prone to javascript injection? If i am creating a shopping cart is it ok to save item ids in the localstorage

Comment: @Kyoko Sasagava Dear Kyogo, i think you questioned something impossible to answer because to be guaranteed "save" all bugs detected in future must be excluded to have influence. I guess a typical solution could be to use cookies, which work for session lifetime even with browsers running in private/incognito mode.

Comment: @KyokoSasagava The client is in full control of both cookies and localStorage and could potentially inject JavaScript (or other harmful code – e.g. SQL injections) in either. On the server side, never trust the data a client sends.

Answer (score 20):

There are addons like e.g. [Foundstone HTML5 Local Storage Explorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foundstone-html5-local-storage/) for Firefox, which permit users not only to browse `localStorage` globally, but also to modify its content:

[image: Local Storage Explorer]

So I wouldn't trust on nobody having access to it or nobody can alter it. At least from the client, it is possible with ease. From another website, it might be more tricky, and certainly would involve a "security hole" as it's not the intended usage.

**Update:** Meanwhile, at least in Firefox, you don't even need any addon for that. Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, select the *Storage* tab, and in the left-most column select *Local Storage* – where you can view and even edit the local storage for the site you've got in the foreground tab:

[image: LocalStorage browser]
<sup>Local Storage browser built-in to Firefox (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Accessing or editing the LocalStorage on your own computer is not a security concern since you are the one brute force your own local resources. It would be a concern if another domain would access the LocalStorage without your help. I assume major browsers are safe with it.

Comment: I'd wish there were an easy snippet to eg export/drop all localstorage for a given domain on-demand – like typing `dropLocalStorage('example.com')`. There are some domains which put new localStorage before you can close their tab after having cleaned it – so one would need to first close the tab, then clean the storage (example: Amazon).

Comment: @profimedica But this _does_ mean that the application shouldn't rely on local storage for e.g. "is this user a super admin?" (Which OP wasn't asking tbf! But it's unfortunately something we do have to be clear about!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can...

1. Go to the website you wish to modify its localstorage.
2. Enter your console (I press F12 in Chrome or Edge).
3. Press the "Application" tab on top.
4. Choose localstorage on the menu and then the website address underneath.
5. Now you have a list of keys and values in front of you.
6. Press the first blank line under them and enter any key on the left and any value on the right that you wish.