# Logged-In state of a user is lost in frontend when page is reloaded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, react-router

I use `express` + `mongodb` + `redis` + `mongoose` as my back-end to provide api.

And, use `react` + `react-router` + `redux` as my front-end.

the authentication is based on `sessionId` + `cookie`.

For front-end, I use `react-router` and `onEnter` hook do the authentication control. When a user logs in successfully, I save the user info from the back-end into redux store. like this:

```
const auth = { username: 'novaline', isLogin: true};
```

Everything is fine so far.

The problem is: **when user reload the page, the data cached in redux store is wiped.** Yeah, I know, redux store has its lifecycle.

But, when a user is logged in & if they reload the page, as the auth data is wiped from redux store, the front-end will lose the user info.

Their username will be undefined and because of the `onEnter` hook, they will be redirected  to `login` page.

But for back-end, the `session` is still in `redis`.

I know `jwt` can solve this problem.

But for my case. How can I keep user's login state when user reload page?

P.S. I set `cookie` `httpOnly` and `Max-Age`. So client can not get or set `cookie`.

__update: __

I try to save user info to localStorage. So, when user logined in, reload page, I check if user info in localStorage or not, if true, I will reset the auth data like this:

`const auth = {username: localStorage.getItem('username'), isLogin: true};`

So, I can use this to implement the auto login and redirect to `home` page.

But I think it's not reliable. User can modify localStorage. So, if user clear localStorage. The user info and login state will also go.

Comment: Saving this information to the local storage would work for persistence. Tried that?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings yeah. I update my question. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Modification of local storage should be of the least concern.
Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246947/can-localstorage-be-modified-by-a-client

Comment: That is the thing about client side code. Anything you set on front end can be modified by the client and probably will be at some point. Do not store sensitive information in local storage and updating server side security is the way to go.

Comment: @keshavDulal I know localStorage has same-origin limit. Is that your point?

Comment: The problem with storing the auth data in localStorage is not the ability to clear the auth data. It is a big problem, that he could authenticate as another user.

Comment: @MaKobi yeah. I provide an extra api to authenticate user when they reload the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `localstorage` for saving login info is not a good practice, since its not secure.

1. Either you allow cookie to be read on the client side and fetch login info from cookie when your redux store inits,
2. Otherwise make an api call when your application loads to get the user logged in status from server.

I'd recommend the second approach.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try your recommend way. It works. Is this the best idea for authentication based on `sessionId` + `cookie` for SPA?

Comment: @novaline Glad it worked. Each way has its pros and cons, The api will require your pwa to work online. So if you need to work offline as well then a different approach (maybe first one) would be needed.