# Hitting url directly takes again to login page even after login Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Firebase authenticaion is integrated in an angular app. Even after logged in to the app, hitting a url or route directly at a new tab or the same tab of browser, chrome, e.g. http://localhost:4200/landing
takes again to the login page.

Is there a way around not to skip login page if it is already log in.

## Steps to reproduce

1. *ng serve* in the angular CLI project takes me to http://localhost:4200/login
2. After login it takes to http://localhost:4200/landing
3. Open a new tab or in the existing tab type, http://localhost:4200/landing hit enter

**Expected**: It stays at http://localhost:4200/landing

**Actual**: It goes back to http://localhost:4200/login

Comment: Is there a way around not to skip login page if it is already log in. ?? Can you explain this line.
If already login should try to skip login

Comment: Pls Share your code then only someone able to help you.

Comment: @eduPeeth, thank for you the comment, I will try to share next time.

Comment: @VickyKumar Thank you for your comment above and below answer. it help me.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from your question is you want to navigate to login page initially, once user is already logged it you want to go to the route which ever he has entered.If not looged in go to login page
You should use localstorage, if you want to preserve any data in browser for new tab or new window
Once you login store some token in local storage. like this

```
localStorage.setItem('userId', 'USERID');
```

Now in your appComponent on init check if local storage doesnot exist then only direct to login.

```
  ngOnInit() {
if (!localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']); // i think initially you are redirecting to login so put condition there in app component
}
}
```

Note: Be careful this will even preserve once you close the browser

Comment: I am not sure if it is checked at ngOnInit it will still hit the isLoggedIn method that AuthGuard is calling.

Comment: Here is my the AuthGuard 
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) { }
  canActivate() {
    if  ( this.authService.isLoggedIn() ) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is how I come up with the solution I have mentioned above. But still I am thinking if someone hack the local storage, then if not logged in also you are able to access the application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246947/can-localstorage-be-modified-by-a-client

Answer (score 0):

I think below changes are required.

```
 constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.userDetails = user;              
// Set the UserId
           localStorage.setItem('userId', user.uid);
        } else {
          this.userDetails = null;
        }
      }
    );
  }


  isLoggedIn() {

    if (this.userDetails == null) {
// Check the UserId
      if (localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
              return true;
      }
      return false;

    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to dashboard or home page in login page  ngOnInit() method. Like this

```
constructor( private router: Router) { }
ngOnInit(): void {if(check_user_login_status){this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);}}
```